# Rails 5: collection_select not saving

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, erb

My form have collection select but no saving to database
Form tryings assign player id to "pretender" record

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vam9k.jpg

database models:

```
 create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "group"
    t.text "info"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pretenders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "archtype"
    t.string "magic"
    t.string "scale"
    t.integer "player_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

in form partial:

```
 <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :player_id %>
        <%= form.collection_select(:player_id, Player.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => '10'}) %>
      </div>
```

generated html select options have value but not saving?

```html
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="pretender[player_id][]">
    <option value="1">sy</option>
    <option value="2">malakal</option>
    <option value="3">pigs go moo</option>
    <option value="4">malgrib</option>
    <option value="5">Rael</option>
    <option value="6">Nargo</option>
    <option value="7">salva</option>
    <option value="8">pbiecub</option>
    <option value="9">Jude</option>
    <option value="10">Cirno</option>
</select>
```

here params at pretender controller:

```
def pretender_params
  params.require(:pretender).permit(:name, :archtype, :magic, :scale, :player_id)
  params.require(:pretender).permit(:id)
end
```

Am attempt solution at:
[Collection_select not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015135/collection-select-not-saving)
& other pages, but site won't let me post more links lol

Comment: Your `pretender_params` is returning `params.require(:pretender).permit(:id)` and ignoring the first line in the method. You might try a single line: `params.require(:pretender).permit(:id, :name, :archtype, :magic, :scale, :player_id)`. Not sure if this is your problem, but I'd change that first and see if it works.

Comment: do you recall? Ruby returns the result of the last statement it executes from a function or closure.

Comment: Okay ty. am remove 2nd line in param. Is work now!

Comment: here workings project! https://my.mixtape.moe/qwplwm.zip